# iOS 11 and Alamofire HTTP error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, alamofire

My code that have been working on previous versions of Xcode and iOS, now has following error:

```
TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c416bd00]: 1:61 Err(61)
HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
```

Code:

```
let params : Parameters = ...
 Alamofire.request("....", parameters: params).responseJSON {
    response in
}
```

Comment: Is you URL http or https?

Comment: its HTTP, but I also tried https and same error...